# Scaffolding in Rails 4 doesn't include id in JSON response

Tags: json, response, ruby-on-rails-4

When I scaffold "customer" in Rails4

> rails g scaffold customer name

JSON response doesn't include "id"

```
curl http://localhost:3000/customers.json

[{"name":"Test 1","url":"http://localhost:3000/customers/1.json"}]
```

How can I add "id"?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using gem **jbuilder** a file **index.json.jbuilder** is generated in *views/customers* folder

It should look like this by default

```
json.array!(@customers) do |customer|
  json.extract! customer, :name
  json.url customer_url(customer, format: :json)
end
```

Just add :id in the second line to see it in json response

```
json.array!(@customers) do |customer|
  json.extract! customer, :name, :id
  json.url customer_url(customer, format: :json)
end
```

New json response will be

```
[{"name":"Test 1","id":1,"url":"http://localhost:3000/customers/1.json"}]
```

Comment: Ran into exactly same problem. Thanks for your self post!

Comment: Thanks @moeso, I'm glad to be helpful :)